# Is there an ASP.NET MVC 2 editor Templates library?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-2

The custom (editor) templates in ASP.NET MVC 2 make it possible to create re-usable UI components (such as a selectlist, radio button list). Even ajax components are possible.

Is there some website where developers can share their custom templates with each other? It seems a bit redudant to write these basic components by my own if thousands of other developers have probably have done so before.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard about one but since it's a good idea you might want to suggest it here:

[World of Visual Studio](http://feedback.wovs.com)

Comment: Thanks, I just have submitted it.